# Angular 2 Component global variable is undefined inside Reactive Form controller valueChanges event

Tags: angular

Inside ngOnInit of my component, I define a reactive form group (inside another form group, but that's not relevant).

For one of the input controllers, I want to watch and act accordingly when a change happens, so I've set `valueChanges.subscribe` and it gets executed as expected.

However, I can not reach **this** component global variable inside event's callback.

```
const company = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required]
});

company.controls['name'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    //All `this` here are  undefined
    if (/\s/.test(value)) this.spaceEntered = true;
    else if (value && value.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0)
        this.stringEntered = true;
});
```

Why that happens and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am ashamed to admit but this situation has nothing to do with Angular 2, but me forgetting about what context is in Javascript.

Simply putting event handler code ***in a function under component scope*** fixes this situation:

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

    companyFG: FormGroup;
    spaceEntered: boolean;
    stringEntered: boolean;
    .
    .
    ngOnInit() {
        this.companyFG = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required]
        });
        .
        .
        this.companyFG.controls['name'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.filterCompany(value));
        .
        .
        .
    }

    filterCompany(term: string) {
        if (/\s/.test(term)) this.spaceEntered = true;
        else if (term && term.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 0)
            this.stringEntered = true;
    }

}
```